# why csipsimple use wrong port to answer freeswitch

Tags: port, sip, contacts, freeswitch

android phone CSipSimple<1000> request INVITE → wifi → private network（192.168.1.30） → public network（121.xxx） → freeswitch(public network 47.xxx)

freeswitch see the phone's ip is 121.xxx:31155,and respone to phone in sip with:
rport=31155;received=121.xxx
but the phone  request INVITE still use wrong port:

```
> Contact: <sip:1000@121.xxx:53753;ob>
```

when the other phone want to call this csipsimple <1000>,freeswitch INVITE 1000 use ip/port xxxx:53753,
so CSipSimple<1000> can't got the INVITE message

why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I found the reason.It is firewall's problem.The phone connect with the wifi,the wifi equipment's firewall do not allocate another port when the sip phone change the first port to another port.